# Alpine JS with local storage - x-data showing old/wrong value after page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage, alpine.js

I am trying to toggle dark mode using Alpine JS saving the value in local storage. But when I toggle the dark mode on and off again and refresh the page, the value in the local storage shows 'false' (which is expected) but the x-data shows the wrong value which is 'true'.

```
<!-- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js
<body 
  x-data="{darkMode: localStorage.getItem('dark')}"
  x-init="$watch('darkMode', val => localStorage.setItem('dark', val))"
  x-bind:class="{ 'dark': darkMode }"
>
  
  <p x-show="darkMode">Dark Mode: ON</p>
  <p x-show="!darkMode">Dark Mode: OFF</p>
  
  <button
    @click="darkMode = !darkMode"
  >Toggle Dark Mode</button>
  
</body>
```

Check this fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/darpan_kulkarni/kpr5de0a

1. Turn on the dark mode
2. Turn off the dark mode
3. Refresh the page, it will still show dark mode ON

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local storage stores values as plain text and not boolean, changing `x-data="{darkMode: localStorage.getItem('dark')}"` to `x-data="{darkMode: localStorage.getItem('dark') === 'true'}"` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, `localStorage` stores all values as Strings. To store a boolean value, you could encode it to JSON and then while getting the value, you can decode back from JSON.

So you could change

`x-data="{darkMode: localStorage.getItem('dark')}"` to
`x-data="{darkMode: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark'))}"`

and

`x-init="$watch('darkMode', val => localStorage.setItem('dark', val))"` to
`x-init="$watch('darkMode', val => localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(val)))"`