# Using Alpine JS Persist Plugin to remember the active toggle/tab after refreshing/revisiting a page

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I followed a tutorial and used Alpine js to place a dark mode switcher on my website. it works good, but every time a user refreshed the page they need to choose the dark mode option again. I searched online and found Persist Plugin seems like a solution, however, I don't have any professional background, and only have experience following tutorials online to build my website, so I can't really get it work. Can anyone help me with this? thank you so much :)

Below is the tutorial code I used, it's from a Oxygen Builder tutorial:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<style>
    .darkmode-switcher {
        width: 64px;
        height: 32px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #191919;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .darkmode-switcher__circle {
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        background-color: white;
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }   
</style>

<div class="mode-switcher" x-data="{ darkMode: false, switchMode: function() { this.darkMode = !this.darkMode } }">
    <div class="darkmode-switcher" @click="switchMode()">
        <div class="darkmode-switcher__circle"></div>
    </div>
    <template x-if="darkMode">
        <style>
            .darkmode-switcher {
                background-color: white;
            }
            .darkmode-switcher__circle {
                background-color: black;
                transform: translateX(32px);
            }
            
            .content-wrapper {
                background-color: black;
            }
            
            .content {
                color: white;
                background-color: #191919;
            }
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using Local storage. You can store dark mode value inside Local storage and fetch from there.

Comment: Thanks Gulshan, is it possible for you to share the code for me? As I really don't know how to do this, just searching the internet and there are not enough tutorial for me to learn, really appreciated.

Comment: I have never worked with Alpine but I'm pretty sure it will work. I'm sharing stackoverflow link if this can help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838886/alpine-js-with-local-storage-x-data-showing-old-wrong-value-after-page-refresh

Comment: Fantastic!Thanks Gulshan, this link is so helpful, I followed the solution and it seems working now on my site. really appreciate your help :)

Comment: you are always Welcome!

Comment: Hi Gulshan, sorry I found another small issue, the localstorage is working now, however, if I am the dark mode, every time I refresh the page, it will show the default value (non-dark mode) for like 0.5 second and then change to the dark mode automatically. So the user can actually notice that 0.5 flesh. You can have a look at my website https://edutive.com.au/. Do you know what's the possible reason for this? many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about it but I think it takes little bit flesh like time to fetch the value from localstorage. Can you send your implemented version ?

Comment: I used the exact solution you referred in the above link `x-data="{ darkMode: localStorage.getItem('dark') === 'true', switchMode: function() { this.darkMode = !this.darkMode } }" x-init="$watch('darkMode', val => localStorage.setItem('dark', val))" x-bind:template="{ 'dark': darkMode }"` Also, because my website has cache, might this  be the reason?

Comment: I tried myself but couldn't find the actual reason, sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks Gulshan for your time. No worries, I think it's because when the page loads, the "body" loads before the "dark mode code", so there is 0.5 second of the default body colour and then the dark mode loads so it quickly changes to the dark mode. I tried to move the code before body, but it still happens, Maybe I did it wrong, will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for understanding me and one more thing your website is really very nice. I don't know which tech stack you used but it's really awesome. Last but not least if you don't mind Let's connect on Linkedin.

Comment: Thanks Gulshan, I used Oxygen builder to build the website, it's a great tool for both design and development. I am so happy you like the design of my website. Happy to connect on LinkedIn, what's your profile?

Comment: oh yeah ! excited to connect with you.                                                                               Url - https://www.linkedin.com/in/gulshan-aggarwal-64b4121a3

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to modify Oxygen youtube video.

[Alpine JS with local storage - x-data showing old/wrong value after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838886/alpine-js-with-local-storage-x-data-showing-old-wrong-value-after-page-refresh)

And worked. As an added bonus, anything you put in style under template x-if, will be formatted as well. If you use variable for colors, this will help to change it easier on all your site.

Example:

In your color `var(--clr-background)`

In your stylesheet `:root {--clr-background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);}`

In style under x-if `:root {--clr-background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);}`

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
<body 
x-data="{darkMode: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dark'))}"
x-init="$watch('darkMode', val => localStorage.setItem('dark', JSON.stringify(val)))"
x-bind:class="{ 'dark': darkMode }"
>

</body>

<style>
    .darkmode-switcher {
        width: 64px;
        height: 32px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: hsl(345, 6%, 13%);
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .darkmode-switcher__circle {
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
        border-radius: 80px;
        background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
        transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }   
    
    
</style>


<div class="mode-switcher">
    <div class="darkmode-switcher" @click="darkMode = !darkMode">
        <div class="darkmode-switcher__circle"></div>
    </div>
    


    <template x-if="darkMode">
        <style>

            //* Add new variable colors here *//  
                
            .darkmode-switcher {
                background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
            }
            .darkmode-switcher__circle {
                background-color: hsl(345, 6%, 13%);
                transform: translateX(32px);
            }

            .content-wrapper {
                background-color: hsl(345, 6%, 13%);
            }
            
            .content {
                color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
                background-color: #191919;
            }

        

        </style>
    </template>
</div>
```

Next bonus, if you would like to autodetect dark mode and activate. This code detects if it is dark mode, and saves that it is the first time. So it doesn't auto dark every time.

Add it as js.

```
if(!('hasThisRunBefore' in localStorage)) {
const prefersDark = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: Dark)').matches
localStorage.setItem('dark', true);
localStorage.setItem("hasThisRunBefore", true);
}
```